# Sticky ruler lines in firefox developer edition

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-edition

I've started using Firefox developer edition, after many years of using Firefox with firebug.
A slightly annoying artifact that I cant seem to get rid of are the rule lines - when I select an element (e.g. a button) Firefox developer edition adds rulers to the page (dashed blue lines) and highlights the elements in yellow.

[image]

The issue I'm having is that these rules (sometimes) appear fixed on the page - they don't move with the selected elements and I cant make these rules and highlights disappear (alternatively, I can't make them stick by myself), I've tried every setting in the console, I've tried refreshing the page, all to no avail, the only way I can seem to get rid of them is to navigate to another page and back to my original page.

[image]

Does anyone know a setting, or a keyboard shortcut to make these lines go away? is it a bug in Firefox?

Comment: I can't replicate this in FF developer edition 35.0a2, This might be a bug or Ubuntu UI issue.

Comment: I'm also seeing this issue but with the regular edition of Firefox (with the inspector open of course).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer my own question:

It seems the only way to get rid of the rulers without navigating to another page is to close the inspector, and re-open again (a quick double-press of F12 does it) - others don't have the same issue with the same version of Firefox developer edition, Though I cant find a bug-report about this